# Query if value in list using R and PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, list, where-in

I have a dataframe like this

**df1**

```
ID  value
1   c(YD11,DD22,EW23)
2   YD34
3   c(YD44,EW23)
4
```

And I want to query another database to tell me how many rows had these values in them. This will eventually be done in a loop through all rows but for now I just want to know how to do it for one row.

Let's say the database looks like this:

**sql_database**

```
value  data
YD11   2222
WW20   4040
EW23   2114
YD44   3300
XH29   2040
```

So if I just looked at row 1, I would get:

```
dbGetQuery(con,
       sprintf("SELECT * FROM sql_database WHERE value IN %i", 
               df1$value[1]) %>%
  nrow()


OUTPUT:  
2
```

And the other rows would be :

Row 2: 0

Row 3: 2

Row 4: 0

I don't need the loop created but because my code doesn't work I would like to know how to query all rows of a table which have a value in an R list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a for loop for this.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)
library(dbplyr)


df1 <- tibble(
  id = 1:4,
  value = list(c("YD11","DD22","EW23"), "YD34", c("YD44","EW23"), NA)
)

# creating in memory database table
df2 <- tibble(
  value = c("YD11", "WW20", "EW23", "YD44", "XH29"),
  data = c(2222, 4040, 2114, 3300, 2040)
)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
# Add auxilary schema
tmp <- tempfile()
DBI::dbExecute(con, paste0("ATTACH '", tmp, "' AS some_schema"))
copy_to(con, df2, in_schema("some_schema", "some_sql_table"), temporary = FALSE)

# counting rows
df1 %>%
  unnest(cols = c(value)) %>%
  left_join(tbl(con, dbplyr::in_schema("some_schema", "some_sql_table")) %>% collect(), by = "value") %>%
  mutate(data = if_else(is.na(data), 0, 1)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(data))
```

Comment: okay this works however in my case I am refering to a table in a schema which I can see with "SELECT * FROM schema.sql_database"  how can I join while refering to this specific table?

Comment: I have updated the code so that it reads from non default schema.